# Construir una clase iterador python

Tags: python, iteradores

En un ejercicio sobre generación de lotes, tengo una lista de entrada, un tamaño de lote  y como resultado producir los lotes (se descarta el sobrante). Ej :  [3,4,5,8,9,0,1] tamaño de lote 3 -> [3,4,5], [8,9,0], descartando el [1] final

Me piden hacerlo construyendo un clase con iterador (**init** , __next). Pero la verdad no entiendo muy bien En función tradicional tengo este código

```
def batch_generator(input_list, batch_size):
    
    import random
    random.shuffle(input_list)
    
    num_batches = len(input_list) // batch_size
    output, batch = [], []
    i = 1
    j = 0
    while i <= num_batches:
        batch = input_list[j:j + batch_size]
        output.append(batch)
        i += 1
        j += batch_size
    yield output
```

No entiendo bien lo del iterador y construí este código:

```
class Batches:
    
    def __init__(self, input_list, batch_size):
        self.input_list = input_list
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.num_batches = len(self.input_list) // self.batch_size
        self.i = 0
        self.j= 1
        self.output = []
        self.batch = []
        
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        if self.j <= self.num_batches:
            if self.i < self.i + self.num_batches:
                self.batch.append(self.input_list[self.i])
                self.i += 1
            self.output.append(self.batch)
            self.j += 1
            return print(self.output)                
        raise StopIteration
        
def main():
    p = Batches(lst, 3)
    iterator =iter(p)
    while True:
        try:
            elem = next(iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            break

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

Pero no tengo claro si voy por el camino correcto y genera unos lotes pero no avanzo.. Agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que has hecho esta casi bien, excepto por algunas cosas que pueden ser confusas y puedes simplificar, por ejemplo no necesitas 2 variables de control (`i` y `j`) ya que puedes usar *slicing* para obtener una porción de la lista, puedes hacer `list[i: i+batch_size]` y con eso obtendrás la primera porción de la lista. Tampoco necesitas 2 lista auxiliares para guardar el resultado, utilizando una *list comprehension* es suficiente (si no te permiten usarlo puedes optar por un `for` normal utilizando una sola lista). También puedes ahorrarte un `try/except` si usas un ciclo `for` pues este parará en el momento que ocurra un `StopIteration` de igual forma tampoco necesitarás el `next()` pues el `for` ya hace uno implícitamente.

```py
class Batches:
    def __init__(self, lista, batch):
        self.batch_size = batch
        self.lista = lista
        self.num_batches = len(lista)//batch
        self.i = 0
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        if self.i<self.num_batches:
            self.i+=1
            return [self.lista.pop(0) for _ in range(self.batch_size)]
        raise StopIteration

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.lista)
```

En cuanto al *inicializador* solo he colocado los atributos necesarios, como es la longitud de los bloques (`bacth_size`), la lista, el número de bloques (`num_batches`) y un contador (`i`) para tener un registro de cuantos bloques van siendo procesador. En el método `__next__` solo se verifica que la variable `i` sea menor que el número de bloques y si lo es simplemente retornamos una lista con los elementos necesarios, para ello usamos una *list comprehension* la cual va quitando elementos de la lista original y este ciclo se repite según el `batch_size`. Si en caso no pue*das o no entiendes la *list comprehension* puedes hacer un `for` normal, así:

```py
    def __next__(self):
        if self.i<self.num_batches:
            self.i+=1
            res = []
            for _ in range(self.batch_size):
                res.append(self.lista.pop(0))
            return res
        raise StopIteration
```

Donde vamos quitando el primer elemento de la lista original y ese mismo elemento lo agregamos a la lista que retornaremos y eso se repite según `batch_size` de esa forma no tenemos que utilizar variables de control para obtener el rango de elementos y tampoco utilizamos *slicing*.

Con eso ya tenemos todo y solo falta usarlo:

```py
batches = Batches([3,4,5,8,9,0,1], 3)
for i in batches:
    print(i)
```

Que dará como resultado:

```
[3, 4, 5]
[8, 9, 0]
```

Además he agregado el método `__repr__`  para poder imprimir la clase y poder ver sus elementos, por lo que si hacemos `print(batches)` veremos:

```
[1]
```

Comment: Excelente ayuda.  La verdad tengo una pregunta adicional y es yo tenia entendído que el iterador precisamente era orientado a no tener un ciclo for , sino para reemplazarlo.  no es así?

Comment: No necesariamente, muchas veces necesitas de un iterador para poder tener control de cuando pasarás al siguiente elemento (con el uso de `next`) pero como no es tu caso entonces se puede usar un `for` para simplificarte el trabajo, ya que obtendrás todos los elementos *"de un tirón"*.  Todo depende de tus necesidades (incluso puedes usar `next` en el mismo `for`)